# How to put the url to let user filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a quick question and kind find a good solution for it. I basically want to filter my contacts by name, but I want the user to put the filter like this in the URL: `/contacts/name=Jonny`.

How can I place the URL on the routes?

I did this:

```
router.get('/contatos?nome',function(req,res){

});
```

I want to let the user filter for something else, like number and so he get all the contacts with the specific number like this `/contacts/number=9123123`. I want to use the same route for that how can I do that?

Comment: router.get('/contacts/:name',function(req,res){

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use [params](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters)

```
router.get('/contacts/:name', (req, res, next) => {
  // you can read name here
  let name = req.params.name.split('=')[1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing `router.get('/contacts/number=(\\d+))')` and then use `req.params[0]`